# Object from Salesforce is interpreted as a String in Google Apps Script/Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, salesforce

We pull data from Salesforce into a Google Doc, Google Apps Script is getting a HTTP-request from Salesforce. We have a object called "products" from salesforce but Google Apps Script interpreting it as a String.

```
function doGet(product)

var productVar = product;

Logger.log(productVar);
```

And the results is like this:

```
"(OpportunityProduct1:{Product10Id=01726388aaa, Quantity=4.00, ListPrice=3.0, Sales_Price__A=3.00})"
```

Can we get it as a Object, or in any way convert it to an object/list/array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First edit the string with JavaScript string methods.

```
function processString() {

  var originalStr = "(OpportunityProduct1:{Product10Id=01726388aaa, Quantity=4.00, ListPrice=3.00, Sales_Price__A=3.00})";
  var i=0, thisCharacter = "";
  //Remove spaces
  for (i=0;i<originalStr.length;i+=1) {
    thisCharacter = originalStr[i];
    //Logger.log(thisCharacter)
    if (thisCharacter === " ") {
      Logger.log(i);
      var front = originalStr.slice(0,i);
      var back = originalStr.slice(i+1);
      originalStr = front + back;
    };
  };

  Logger.log(originalStr)
  var strNewObject = "";

  var myRegEx = new RegExp("=","g");

  strNewObject = originalStr.replace(myRegEx, '":"');

  strNewObject = strNewObject.replace("{", '{"');
  strNewObject = strNewObject.replace("}", '"}');
  strNewObject = strNewObject.replace(/,/g, '","');

  strNewObject = strNewObject.replace("(", '{"'); //Need out curly brace for valid JSON
  strNewObject = strNewObject.replace(")", "}"); //Need out curly brace for valid JSON
  strNewObject = strNewObject.replace(":", '":'); //

  Logger.log('strNewObject: ' + strNewObject);

  var newObject = JSON.parse(strNewObject);

  Logger.log(newObject);
  Logger.log(typeof newObject);


  Logger.log(newObject.OpportunityProduct1.Quantity)
};
```

You can convert a string back to an object with `JSON` service:

```
var myNewObject = JSON.parse(productVar);
```

Use the quick keys "Ctrl" + "Space bar" in the Apps Script editor to bring up a list of available services.

Comment: Will Apps Script's JSON parser accept this syntax? Salesforce is returning `Name=Value` instead of `"Name":Value`. It might be necessary to do some string manipulation (or write a reviver function)

Comment: No that's true, the string from Salesforce is not a JSON string, it's "just a string". We are really stuck.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks.  The string could probably be searched for "function" first: `if (strObj.indexOf("function") !== -1) {return}; `

Comment: You are amazing guys, Thank you so much, can't believe no one else have asked this question before. This works perfect! Sandy, you should change your nick to Sandy GOD :]

Comment: Haha.  I wouldn't want to insult God.  I think the question has probably been asked before, but maybe in terms of converting a PHP object literal to a JavaScript option, or something like that.  But the problem is, unless you know the exact terminology to search for it can be hard to find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply `var productObject = eval(productVar);` if you trust it to not contain malicious code.